# python issue with global name not being defined

Tags: python

So I'm trying to write the user interface for a round of golf.  I already have Player and League classes defined and I don't want to change them.  In my user interface, I need it to be able to enter the scores of 9 holes for a text file of players, and return the gross score, par, and birdies for each player.  I am getting an error in my enterScores function that position is not defined.  I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
class Player:
""" Represents a player in the golf league """

    PAR = [4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5]
    """ par for each of the 9 holes """

    def __init__(self, name):
        """ creates a Player and keeps track of stats """
        self.__name = name
        self.__pars = 0
        self.__birdies = 0
        self.__gross = 0

    def getName(self):
        """ returns a player's name """
        return self.__name

    def getGross(self):
        """ returns a player's gross score """
        return self.__gross

    def getPars(self):
        """ returns number of pars made """
        return self.__pars

    def getBirdies(self):
        """ returns number of birdies made """
        return self.__birdies

    def recordScores(self, holeScores):
        """ mutator method that uses the results of one round of play
          (9 holes) to update a player's stats """
        self.__gross = sum(holeScores)
        self.__findparsandbirdies(holeScores)

    def __findparsandbirdies(self, scores):
        """ helper method that finds the number of pars and birdies """

        pars = 0
        birdies = 0
        hole = 0
        for score in scores:
            if score == Player.PAR[hole]:
                pars += 1
            if score == Player.PAR[hole] - 1:
                birdies += 1
            hole += 1
        self.__pars = pars
        self.__birdies = birdies

    def __str__(self):
        """ returns a string representation of a player """
        return 'a Player named ' + self.__name

class League:
""" represents the players of a golf league """

    def __init__(self, fileName = 'players.txt'):
        """ creates a list of Player objects from the
            names stored in the file specified """
        self.__playerList = []
        datafile = open(fileName, 'r')
        for line in datafile:
            playerName = line.rstrip()
            player = Player(playerName)
            self.__playerList.append(player)

    def getNumPlayers(self):
        """ returns the number of players is the league """
        return len(self.__playerList)

    def getPlayerbyPosition(self, position):
        """ returns the player at the specified position """
        return self.__playerList[position]

    def getPlayerbyName(self, name):
        """ returns the player with the specified name """
        for player in self.__playerList:
            if player.getName() == name:
                return player
        return None

    def __str__(self):
        return 'a golf league with ' + str(self.getNumPlayers()) + ' players'



def main():
    """The input and output for the program"""
    l= League()
    players= []
    enterScores(l, players, position)
    isValidScore(holeScores)
    output(players)


def enterScores(l, players, position):
    """enter the scores"""
    for pos in range(l.getNumPlayers()):
        holeScores= input(("Please enter a list of the player's scores: "))
        while not isValidScore(holeScores):
            holeScores= input(("Please enter a valid list of scores: "))
        p= l.getPlayerbyPosition(position)
        players.append(player)
        player.recordScores(holeScores)


def isValidScore(holeScores):
    """checks if the scores entered for a single hole are 1 to 10, inclusive"""
    for score in holeScores:
        if score == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10:
            return True
        else:
            return False                


def output(grossScore, pars, birdies):
    """prints output"""
    for player in players:
        print(player.getName())
        print('Gross score:', player.getGross())
        print('Pars: ', player.getPars())
        print('Birdies: ', player.getBirdies())
```

Comment: You need to indent all the class methods.

Comment: Thanks, they are in the actual code, I just made a mistake copying it here

Comment: Maybe edit the question, adding the proper indentation, so that it's easier to follow the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not defining position either within main() (or globally).

```
position = 10
```

You could also just enter it in the function call:

```
enterScores(l, players, 10)
```

Comment: This wont really work though, because I need it to work for all the players in the league, not just one player in whatever position I put in

Comment: I guess I'm not sure why you're sending a position to that function, then. You might just need to query the position when entering the score?

Comment: Maybe that part is not necessary then for what I'm trying to do.  I just need a way to have each player in the text file be added to my player list.

Comment: Even if it's not relevant, you'll at least have to modify the code to prevent the error posed in the question. You might need to redefine what your problem is and maybe submit another question?

Comment: @tinydancer9454: Don't forget that you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the green checkmark next to it.